# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 in android

Tags: android

In my android appliction, I have to create Bitmaps continually, this is the code:

```
@Override
protected byte[] getTile(int level, int col, int row) {
    double[] bbox = getBBOX(level, col, row);
    byte[] res = Util.getBitMapByteArray(bbox);
    return res;
}


public static byte[] getBitMapByteArray(double[] bbox) {
    Bitmap map = MapEngine.GetBitMap(bbox);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

And I got the errors when the `getTile` is triggered, and my application will exit the current activity and back to the previous activity:

```
12-10 10:25:43.424: A/libc(12035): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 12035 (droidPlatEngine)
12-10 10:25:43.424: A/libc(12035): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 12102 (Thread-4336)
```

And the `MapEngine.GetBitMap` will call a native method by from native library.

Since the calling of the method `getTile` is by other component which is out of my control(it may call the method from multiple threads) so I try to add `synchronized` keyword to both the two methods.:

```
@Override
protected synchronized byte[] getTile(int level, int col, int row) {
    double[] bbox = getBBOX(level, col, row);
    byte[] res = Util.getBitMapByteArray(bbox);
    return res;
}


public static synchronized byte[] getBitMapByteArray(double[] bbox) {
    Bitmap map = MapEngine.GetBitMap(bbox);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

Now, my application can run for a moment, but the same errors will still occur again at some time.

Then I tried to use the DDMS to see what happened, this is the heap dialog:

[image]

Also I found that if I keep hitting the `cause GC` button, my app will run for a long time, and exit to the previous acitivty if I stop hit the button.

Now I am not sure if this is caused by the thread or the memory, by my java code or the native library.

Anybody can tell me how to continue?